# jQuery multi level selector does not work but .children does

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript code which works fine

```
var QuestionID = panel.siblings('.QuestionIDWrapper').children('input[type=hidden]').val();
```

but if I convert it to use a multi level jQuery selector like this:

```
var QuestionID = panel.siblings('.QuestionIDWrapper input[type=hidden]').val();
```

I don't get any value in QuestionID.

Comment: Any chance to see the actual markup?

Comment: dont forget to mark asnwer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the docs: http://api.jquery.com/siblings/
You didn't provide the actual markup, but I assume that while .QuestionIDWrapper is a silbing, input[type=hidden] is not a direct silbing, only a silbings child. (and not matched therefore)

Answer (score 2):

The second one will only select a sibling of `panel` if it *matches the provided selector*.  Since  your input is a child of one of `panel`'s siblings, then it is not at the same level (not a sibling).

Answer (score 1):

`.QuestionIDWrapper input[type=hidden]` - for this to work input element must be 
    immidiate child of QuestionIDWrapper class element.

You are using : [Descendant Selector (“ancestor descendant”)](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

Where as in the first one you are seching for the childer elemtn with the specific selector.

Comment: If the input[type=hidden] is a child of the .QuestionIDWrapper why would the descendant selector code not work?  The code is generated by an ASPX HiddenField, so I suspect it has some extra spans, etc involved.  (I haven't checked the generated code).